# Entity Framework, Fluent API relationships - many-to-one-or-zero

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to setup a specific relationship using FluentAPI on 2 entities. See details below

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory: Entity
{
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public string Set_num { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<InventoryPart> InventoryParts { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryPart : Entity
{
    public int Inventory_id { get; set; }
    public string Part_num { get; set; }
    public int Color_id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Is_spare { get; set; }
    public string Img_url { get; set; }                        
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual UserPart? UserPart { get; set; }
}

public class UserPart : Entity
{                
    public string Part_num { get; set; }          
    public int Color_id { get; set; }        
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }   
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<InventoryPart> InventoryParts { get; set; }
}
```

`OnModelCreating` code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .HasMany(b => b.InventoryParts)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(lim => lim.Inventory_id);
        
modelBuilder.Entity<InventoryPart>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.Part_num, l.Color_id }); // This IS NOT unique! Inventory_id, Part_num, Color_id, Is_spare would be the unique compound key
                
modelBuilder.Entity<UserPart>()
            .HasKey(u => new { u.Part_num, u.Color_id }); // This IS unique

modelBuilder.Entity<UserPart>()
            .HasMany(u => u.InventoryParts)
            .WithOne(l => l.UserPart)
            .HasForeignKey(l => new { l.Part_num, l.Color_id });
```

The goal is to filter an `InventoryPart` and include `InventoryParts` and the linked `UserPart`.

```
public class GetSetPartsBySpecification : Specification<Inventory>, ISingleResultSpecification
{
    public GetSetPartsBySpecification(string setnum)            
    {
        Query
            .Where(inv => inv.Set_num == setnum)                            
            .Include(ip => ip.InventoryParts)
                .ThenInclude(ip=>ip.UseParts)
            .AsSplitQuery();
    }
}
```

**Notes** on the data: `Inventory` and `InventoryParts` are imported into a SQLite database periodically. `Inventory.Id` is the `InventoryPart.Inventory_id` and is NOT autogenerated, it gets the value from the Excel import file.

An `InventoryPart` has a many-to-one-or-zero relationship with `UserPart`.

A `UserPart` has a one-to-many relationship with `InventoryPart`.

I don't need the reverse relationship, `UserParts.InventoryParts`

**Question**

Is it possible to define a relationship using Fluent API on the above entities structure? You can see my attempt above. I get an error because .HasKey(l => new { l.Part_num, l.Color_id }) on the `InventoryPart` is not unique.

**Notes**

I have a version of this working using a set of tables that I create during the import process but I would prefer to us the existing data structure. I can add that code if requested.

Comment: Are you trying to map entity classes/relations to existing database tables/relationships or the other way around (code first and migrations for updating database structure)?

Comment: Code first and migrations. The data is from an external source in Excel. I create entities that match the exact structure of that data.

Answer (score 0):

`HasKey` is for defining the *primary key* of an entity. Since  none of the following are primary keys, *remove* them both

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<InventoryPart>()
    .HasKey(l => new { l.Part_num, l.Color_id }); // This IS NOT unique! Inventory_id, Part_num, Color_id, Is_spare would be the unique compound key
                
modelBuilder.Entity<UserPart>()
    .HasKey(u => new { u.Part_num, u.Color_id }); // This IS unique
```

Instead, use `HasForeignKey` / `HasPrincipalKey` to define key property(es) for both sides of the relationship

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<UserPart>()
    .HasMany(u => u.InventoryParts)
    .WithOne(l => l.UserPart)
    .HasForeignKey(l => new { l.Part_num, l.Color_id })
    .HasPrincipalKey(u => new { u.Part_num, u.Color_id })
    .IsRequired(false);
```

This will define unique composite key in principal entity table, and non unique composite foreign key in the dependent entity table.

Note however that optional relationship requires nullable FK column(s), so in your case you have to change the types of the properties in the `InventoryPart` class (make them both nullable):

```cs
public class InventoryPart : Entity
{
    //...
    public string? Part_num { get; set; }
    public int? Color_id { get; set; }
    // ...
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual UserPart? UserPart { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

This should do what you are asking for. Don't forget to generate and apply new migration after making the aforementioned mods.

Comment: Thanks. made the changes. Recreated the DB (applied the migration). I get a SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'. when it tries to save the Inventory_Part data. Its the first record in the file. This is the constraint created on the table in SQLite - CONSTRAINT "FK_inventory_parts_userparts_Part_num_Color_id" FOREIGN KEY ("Part_num", "Color_id") REFERENCES "userparts" ("Part_num", "Color_id"). The particular part its erroring on does not exisit in the UserParts data.

Comment: Well, this is how FK relationships work in relational databases, which EF Core is based on. Optional doesn't mean the dependent table could refer to non existing record in the principal table. If this is what you are looking for, then you can't use EF Core navigation properties and database relations, remove/unmap all these from the model and then use manual joins for querying etc.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and time. Ill keep at it.